# Intermitent connection drop with iOS Browser/F5

Tags: ios, xmlhttprequest, f5

We have an IIS website(ASP.net) that work at many location. We have a client where the website is hosted on IIS behind an F5(Big IP). When the client is connecting we have intermittent lost of connection. The issue arises more often with the Safari or Chrome on Iphone. I have tried many things to find the issue but I'm running out of idea.

Here is a Network trace gathered with Safari. You will see that I have many red lines that are requests that did not make it to the server. The requests for resources named 6-*.ice are images while the 4-*.ice are XHR requests: 
[Safari Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrIG7.png)
The XHR Request HTTP Status was 0. When it happens, we redirect the user to the BadRequest.htm page.

I have validated the possible issue with HTTP/2 and connection HTTP header but everything is still on HTTP/1.

I will validate if i'm able to get a log with Chrome.

Update:
I have the following tcpdump that was created by an IT guys from is PC:[image: TcpDump]

From is interpretation the TCP RST was raised by Safari but I have to admit I'm no expert in tcpdump so if you need more information please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Golgoth96. You'll probably need to diagnose this with tcpdump at the BIG-IP (F5) or at the IIS server. Without more data, the problem could lie in many different places. Example: HTTP2 and HTTP1.1 have different HTTP profiles on BIG-IP so sending different traffic protocols to the same virtual IP will cause issues. You'll also need to diagnose what persistence profile is being used and if your client is creating or not using the same session to connect to the app.... a little more digging will be needed to help you better.

Comment: Hello @Chase, I have update my question with a TCP RST log